# F# RX Projection

Tags: f#, system.reactive

Want to convert some C# code for RX to F# code.
The following C# code works well:

```
  var seqNum = Observable.Range(1, 5);
  var seqString = from n in seqNum
                  select new string('*', (int)n);
  seqString.Subscribe(str => { Console.WriteLine(str); });
  Console.ReadKey();
```

The following is my code in F#:

```
#light
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Reactive
open System.Reactive.Linq
open System.Reactive.Subjects
open System.Threading
open System.IO

let seqNum = Observable.Range(1, 5)
let seqString = from n in seqNum
                select new string('*', (int)n)
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

But I got the following compiler error:
Error: Unexpected keyword 'new' in implementation file

If I deleted the new keyword, I got another error:
Error: Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized

The "new" keyword are totally different in C# and F#.
Please show me how to do the same job in F#.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Reactive
open System.Reactive.Linq

let seqString = Observable.Range(1,5).Select(fun x -> String.replicate x "*")
using (seqString.Subscribe (fun x -> printfn "%s" x))
    (fun _ -> Console.ReadLine() ) |> ignore
```

**EDIT**: As Paul suggested below two last lines can be replaced by simple

```
seqString.Subscribe (printfn "%s") |> ignore
```

However, if we want to gracefully unsubscribe from our subscription, but get rid of `using` in lieu of newer `use` syntax we may replace last two lines by the following three

```
do
    use subscription = seqString.Subscribe(printfn "%s")
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Comment: You don't need to (and in fact, shouldn't) Dispose the subscription here

Comment: @PaulBetts: (a) `Console.ReadLine()` within `using` block guarantees that disposal will take place only **after ** pressing `Enter` on keyboard as original C# code suggests; and (b) more importantly, `Observable.Range(1,5)` is equivalent to `Observable.Range(1,5,Scheduler.CurrentThread)` making the code effectively single-threaded, so disposing subscription here is absolutely safe, why shouldn't I?

Comment: Hi, Gene Belitski: Thank you very much, your code works.  However, it is difficult for me to know when to use "use" and when to use "using", I am thinking only C# uses "using", not F#!

Comment: Because the semantics of IObservable.Subscribe are that you Dispose it only if you want to terminate the subscription early. In this case, you don't *want* to dispose it early, and the only way you get away with it is that the source is scheduled in-context

Comment: @JohnJohn: You may want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973795/f-keyword-use-and-using) for explanations of difference between `use` and `using`. But you also can safely stick to `use`, which is a syntactic sugar  form of binding that ensures automagical call of `Dispose()` when `IDisposable` value goes out of scope

Answer (score 3):

In C# `string` is the shortcut to `System.String` class. However, in F# `string` is a function which has `obj` as its input and returns a string which is overriden in `obj.ToString()`:

```
let s = string('*', 3);; // tuple to string
// val s : string = "(*, 3)"
```

What you really want is creating a string by repeating `'*'` three times:

```
let s = new String('*', 3)
// val a : String = "***"
```

To be clear, `from ... in ... select ...` is C# LINQ syntax which is invalid in F#. Therefore, using computation expression instead:

```
let seqNum = seq {1..5}
let seqString = seq { for n in seqNum -> new String('*', n) }
```

To get some ideas of creating/using computation expression for Reactive Extension, take a look at the question and its answers at [How do I change the Rx Builder implementation to fix the stack overflow exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162288/how-do-i-change-the-rx-builder-implementation-to-fix-the-stack-overflow-exceptio)

Comment: Hi, Pad:
Thank you, your code works.
However, from the original C# code, I don't know how to subscribe to the Observable.
Please show me how I can subscribe to it.

Comment: @John: you were too fast to accept the pad's answer. See below my working F# port of your original C# snippet. Though you cannot use LINQ in F# C# way, nevertheless you can use it thru "dot" notation.

Comment: Something like `seqString.Subscribe(fun s -> Console.WriteLine(s))` would work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `String` constructor use the `String.replicate` method.

```
String.replicate n "*"
```

There is no direct equivalent for `String(char, int)` but `String.replicate: int -> string -> string` is roughly the equivalent with `string` instead of `char`

F# version for that code

```
[1 .. 5]
|> Seq.map (fun i -> String.replicate i "*")
```

Comment: Hi: JaredPar:
I changed my code to:
let seqString = from n in seqNum
                select (String.replicate n "*")
But I got even more terrible compiler error:
Error: The value or constructor 'from' is not defined
The F# compiler did NOT even recogize keyword "from" for LINQ.
Tell me what to do.
Thanks!

Comment: @JohnJohn I thought you were using the preview version that they added LINQ to (pretty sure it's added there).  The RTM version doesn't have any support for LINQ.  I'll add the equivalent F# version for that particular code.

Comment: Hi, JaredPar: I have changed my code to look like this: let xx = [1 .. 5]
       |> Seq.map (fun i -> String.replicate i "*")
       |> (fun x -> x.ToObservable())
       |> (fun y -> y.Subscribe(printfn "%s"))

Comment: Hi, JaredPar: your code is better, but it didn't do what the original code did: to subscribe from an observable.  I added some code that do the job, let me know what you think!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JohnJohn I'm less familiar with `Observable` but your code does look correct to me.